# Maximum security web browser

Tags: web-browser, security

I recently upgraded Firefox and it screwed up the NoScript UI and greatly increased CPU usage. When I downgraded to an older version, it deleted my Adblock Plus and NoScript installs instead of looking for the most recent compatible versions.

I'm looking for a new web browser where maximum security comes standard as the main feature. In particular, an extremely aggressive ad blocker and something like NoScript built in by default. No exceptions are allowed for ad blocking except those that the user specifically allows.

Bonus points:

- includes a tool that automatically scans all scripts and page elements for malicious or possibly malicious code or sites and blocks them pre-emptively.
- Regularly updated automatic blacklist of known malicious sites and malicious script hosts.
- Specifically designed to prevent sites from detecting the presence of an ad blocker (some sites actively check for ad blockers).
- Full JavaScript sandboxing per tab. Scripts loaded in 1 tab are forbidden from interacting with any other tab. Additionally, scripts are never saved in any form after the tab is closed (including cache), preventing malicious scripts from saving a cached file that spawns advertisements or malware (this happened to my mother's computer several times and I had to clean them out with an antivirus scanner). This also prevents keylogger and mouselogger scripts loaded in a tab from nabbing your logins and other important data in other tabs.
- Optional blocking by estimated geographic location of sites and scripts. Most malware originates in Russia, China, and Eastern Europe - therefore it would be a favor to end-users outside those locations to treat web content from those locations with extra prejudice (in practice any country or geographic location can be added to the blacklist). This would also thwart some malicious redirects and JS includes from legitimate/previously trusted sites that have been hacked or mistakenly host infected adverts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tor Browser is slow because of the overhead of the Tor anonymizing overlay network, so it is probably not what you are looking for.

[**Brave**](https://brave.com/) is an open source, cross-platform web browser for Windows, Mac and Linux. Brave is fast, lightweight, and includes advanced ad tracker blocking controls. Brave includes HTTPS Everywhere integration, blocks cookie capture, script blocking is built-in, and features a decent ad blocker.

Brave browser blocks a lot of pop-up windows that can make browsing a frustrating and unpleasant experience. Most of the time this is a good thing unless you are visiting a website that serves some of its content as links that when clicked open up overlay pop-up windows on the same page. Brave browser will sometimes not open these pop-up windows even when the link is clicked. If you want to see the pop-up window you need to open the same webpage in another web browser.

Comment: Seems to be [exclusively available for 64-bit on Linux](https://brave.com/download/).

Comment: At the official [Brave web browser download](https://brave.com/download/) website it says that Brave web browser for Linux is only available for 64-bit architecture operating systems, so there is no 32-bit version available. [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984080/how-to-install-brave-web-browser-for-32-bit-lubuntu-16-04/984081#984081)

Comment: Is Brave based on Cromium, Mozilla, Webkit, or something else? What is the code quality of the Brave browser?

Comment: *Brave web browser is a free and open-source web browser based on the Chromium web browser and its Blink engine,* [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brave_(web_browser))